# Wireguard and zerotier not forwarding through CGNAT

Tags: networking, ipv6, nat, forwarding

I requested IPv6 networks from Route48.org and august.tw. Both offer wireguard tunnels and I connected to both at the same time with a 20 second keep alive. I also ran a test http server. connecting to the HTTP server from the IP's locally works, but connecting from any other device, LAN or global, does not work.

I requested another IPv6 network from Route48 using zerotier. the network also did not work from any other device

My ISP uses CGNAT on IPv4 and although it offers native IPv6 it is completely firewalled on the ISP side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the tunnel not forwarding packets, and not with your webserver replying in the wrong direction? Have you checked using tcpdump or Wireshark what's actually happening there?

Comment: So you have two IPv6 uplinks (VPN and “regular”), is that correct? What measures are in place to ensure that traffic originating from “VPN subnets” enters the VPN?

Comment: @user1686 I used wireshark and the HTTP packets are sent through loopback interface. what do I do here?